# Redirecionar saída do System.out.println para JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Estou tendo problemas para fazer esse redirecionamento, vamos a explicação.
Eu possuo uma classe chamada `Engine.java`, essa classe é responsável por fazer meu processamento e nela tem todos os `System.out.prints` do processo, o problema é que agora eu criei uma janela utilizando Java Swing, e gostaria de nela chamar esse método, e queria que todo o texto do `System.out.print` fosse para um `JTextArea` criado por mim. É possível?

Comment: Você quer interceptar a saida do println pro JTextArea? Mal pergunte, são tantos println assim? Talvez o trabalho que você vai ter fazendo esse "hacking", seria o que você poderia fazer para adaptar o código pro swing. Em opção ao JTextArea, não pode ser um JOptionPane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes we can!**

Sim, é possível mudar o objeto `System.out` que normalmente vai para o console usando o método [`System.setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-). Basta então passar uma instância de `PrintStream` que direcione o conteúdo para o seu `TextArea`.

Um problema que você pode enfrentar é que o construtor de `PrintStream` recebe como parâmetro um `OutputStream`.

Logo, você  vai precisar criar um `OutputStream` para direcionar o texto escrito, sobrescrevendo o método `write(byte)`, ou seja, vai ter que trabalhar com bytes e não com String ou caracteres.

Uma forma de fazer isso é usando um `ByteArrayOutputStream` para coletar os bytes escritos e depois transformar em String novamente.

## Código de exemplo

Observe um exemplo que fiz abaixo:

```
PrintStream original = System.out;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        baos.write(b);
    }
    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        sb.append(baos.toString());
        baos.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        sb.append(baos.toString());
        baos.reset();
    }
}, true));

//tudo o que for escrito será capturado
System.out.print("Capture ");
System.out.println("Isto ");
System.out.format("Para %s!", "Mim");

//restaurando o original para escrever no console
System.setOut(original);
System.out.format("Resultado capturado:%n%s", sb);
```

Basicamente, fiz uma implementação de `OutputStream` conforme mencionei acima, que guarda os dados num array de bytes.

Quando ocorre o `flush` ou `close`, o código adiciona os dados num `StringBuilder`. No seu caso, basta mudar isso para concatenar ao `TextArea`.

Note que passei um segundo parâmetro ao construtor de `PrintStream` com o valor `true`. Isso faz com o método `flush` seja chamado que cada vez que algo é escrito no `PrintStream`. Se não colocar isso, os dados não serão exibidos enquanto o buffer não ficar cheio, pois `PrintStream` usa um `BufferedOutputStream` internamente, e pode ser que algumas informações não sejam exibidas na sua `TextArea` quando você esperava.

## Um alerta

Não é considerada boa prática escrever no `System.out`.

Se o seu programa é algo mais que um exercício ou projeto acadêmico, você **deve** usar uma biblioteca de logs como [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) ou Log4J.

Essas bibliotecas são muito mais flexíveis e permitem configurar quais dados serão coloca no log, em que formato, etc.